# In Pandas for np.nan, why is "mul()" not equal to "__mul__()"?

Tags: pandas, boolean, nan

On a simple Pandas Series, when I am comparing the results of `mul()` and `__mul__()`, there is a 'False' boolean that is being returned for NaN value.

Why?

```
    x = pd.Series([0,1,2,np.nan,5])

    x.mul(1) == x.__mul__(1)

Result:
    0     True
    1     True
    2     True
    3    False
    4     True
    dtype: bool
```

Comment: `NaN` never compares equal to anything, not even itself.  That's part of its definition.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge. That helps.

Answer (score 1):

One of the defining properties of `NaN` is that it is not equal to itself. See [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

So when `x` equals `np.nan`, presumably `x.mul(1)` and `x.__mul__(1)` are both `np.nan` again, and the result of testing this value for equality with itself is false.